# Web API route is ignored and processed by MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, url-routing

I can't figure out why a route is being processed by MVC instead of Web API.

The whole route is configured as follows:

```
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute
(
    name: "AdminControllers.TicketingController",
    routeTemplate: "api/company/tickets",
    defaults: new 
    { 
        controller = "Ticketing", 
        id = RouteParameter.Optional, 
        action = "GetTickets" 
    }
);
```

And the API controller looks like this:

```
public sealed class TicketingController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetTickets()
    {
        return ControllerContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

I perform a HTTP/GET request to `/api/company/tickets` and I get the following error:

> The controller for path "/api/company/tickets" was not
>   found or does not implement IController.

Exception's stack trace points to ASP.NET MVC (not Web API): `System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)`.

AFAIK, this happens when you map a route using the wrong framework (MVC) instead of Web API `HttpConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute` extension method. In my sample found above you'll find I'm using the right resource to register a controller in Web API.

I can confirm that the route gets registered during application startup.

The problem is ASP.NET MVC pipeline handles the route and, obviously, it does find no controller for the whole route.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

NOTE: It's ASP.NET Web API 1.x and I can't use Web API 2.0 (I would love to use attribute routing, yeah).

### Update: A pic of registered routes after invoking `.MapHttpRoute(...)`

[image]

### Update 2

Believe or not, but it started to work when I changed route configuration to:

```
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "AdminControllers.TicketingController",
    routeTemplate: "api/company/tickets/{id}",
    defaults: new 
    { 
        controller = "Ticketing", 
        id = RouteParameter.Optional, 
        action = "GetTickets" 
    }
);
```

And Web API action changed to:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetTickets(int? id)
{
    return ControllerContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

It seems like a route parameter makes the route different enough to be ignored by MVC and then processed by Web API pipeline. But I can confirm that there's no other route starting with "api/company/".

Anyway, it works if I give the `id` (f.e. `/api/company/tickets/11`). Otherwise, MVC pipeline processes the route...

Comment: can you drop a breakpoint and confirm your MapHttpRoute call is actually being made?

Comment: @RobertLevy I confirmed that, it's mapped! I've tried now to perform a GET request to /api/company/tickets/WHATEVER and then I get a blank 404. It seems like I map using Web API and it gets handled by MVC...!

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer: Could you post the piece of code where you register the web api and mvc routes?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi The Web API part is what you see, and MVC will be impossible, because it's a site part of Windows Azure Pack (closed source)

Comment: what order do they happen in?

Comment: @RobertLevy I'm registering the whole route using a custom HTTP module, and it's the first module in the entire pipeline. I mean that my route gets registered before MVC ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking for solutions, I've got a working one.

First of all, I'm deploying a Web API controller to Windows Azure Pack administrator's site (AdminSite). It's made with ASP.NET MVC 4.0. Anyway, I believe my answer should make sense if you find the same problem I'm going to describe in any ASP.NET MVC and Web API mixed application.

#### Windows Azure Pack registers this ASP.NET MVC route: `{controller}/{action}/{id}`: PROBLEM!

*Yes, because it's an URL route that can fit in Web API controller URI scheme...**

[image]

#### So... what?

At the end of the day, this is solved putting Web API routes before MVC ones. This way, ASP.NET will route requests to the first coincidence of some URI route pattern:

```
// #1 we add the whole routes. One for listing, other for getting
// a single entity (ticket)
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Company.AzurePack.Ticketing.List",
    routeTemplate: "api/company/tickets",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Ticketing",
        action = "GetTickets"
    }
);

configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Company.AzurePack.Ticketing.GetOne",
    routeTemplate: "api/company/tickets/{id}",
    defaults: new 
    { 
        controller = "Ticketing", 
        action = "GetTicket" 
    }
);

// #2 we get both added routes from the route table and we create two
// references to them. Later, we remove and re-insert them at the top
// of route table. BINGO!
RouteBase apiRoute1 = RouteTable.Routes[RouteTable.Routes.Count - 1];
RouteBase apiRoute2 = RouteTable.Routes[RouteTable.Routes.Count - 2];
RouteTable.Routes.Remove(apiRoute1);
RouteTable.Routes.Remove(apiRoute2);

RouteTable.Routes.Insert(0, apiRoute1);
RouteTable.Routes.Insert(0, apiRoute2);
```

#### Wait, Web API routes are registered into `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes` route table...

Yes, but `HttpConfiguration.Routes` registers its routes in `RouteTable.Routes` too, and ASP.NET pipeline works with `RouteTable.Routes`. That is, both MVC and WebAPI routes are in the same route table.

In the following screenshot, you'll find that Web API routes are of type `HttpWebRoute`:

[image]

Now these URIs are served by the fancy Web API controller:

- /api/company/tickets
- /api/company/tickets/11

### An extension method to make our life even easier!

After I checked that this solution was working, I refactored above sample code to an extension method:

```
public static class HttpRouteCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IHttpRoute MapHttpRouteAt(this HttpRouteCollection routes, int index, string name, string routeTemplate, object defaults = null, object constraints = null, HttpMessageHandler handler = null)
    {
        Contract.Requires(routes != null);

        IHttpRoute route = routes.MapHttpRoute(name, routeTemplate, defaults, constraints, handler);

        RouteBase apiRoute = RouteTable.Routes[RouteTable.Routes.Count - 1];
        RouteTable.Routes.Remove(apiRoute);

        RouteTable.Routes.Insert(index, apiRoute);

        return route;
    }
}
```

...and now I'm able to add routes at the top of routing table as follows:

```
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRouteAt(
    index: 0,
    name: "sampleRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/some/path/{name}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Some",
        action = "SomeAction",
        httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET")
    }
);
```