# Calling controllers in different folders in ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an 100% javascript application inside my `ASP.NET WebAPI` project. This application consumes all the data from my API methods.

Now, I have been requested to create a simple portal built in Razor and HTML also inside my WebAPI project (so like a MVC project).

So I have created a folder under "**Controllers**" folder named "**Portal**" where Im placing all my portal exclusive controllers.

Here is the Controllers structure folders:

[image]

This is my Razor web application views structure:

[image]

So when I run the application I can see the Login page view (under "**Account**" folder). When I click my Login button, I call my `CommonController` (Portal) to render a Left menu but I get the error:

[image]

I guess because I have 2 `CommonControllers`, but 1 is for serving my javascript application and the other is for my Portal application.

The line in my Index.cshtml that calls the Common controllers is:

```
 <div class="page-header page-header-blue">
  @Html.Action("Header", "Common")
  <h1><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> Dashboard</h1>
</div>
```

In my `WebApiConfig.cs` I have the following Web Api Route:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
            );
```

> So I don't know how to tell it that I want to call `CommonController` that is under "**Portal**" folder.

Any clue or advice on how to do this and the best practice?

**UPDATE:**

I have create other route for my Portal controllers:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultMvc",
               routeTemplate: "portal/{controller}/{action}"
           );
```

Seems to work but in my index.cshtml calls : `@Html.Action("Header", "Common")` how can I tell the action to call `Portal Common` and not just `Common` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web API route is ignored and processed by MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184349/web-api-route-is-ignored-and-processed-by-mvc)

Comment: Read the solution of the possible duplicate but I dont get it..

Comment: I have been thinking in better create another web project only for the portal application.

Comment: I believe it has something to do with my Q&A. It's about how URL routing module prioritizes routes

Comment: Matias how do you think if I create better a separate project? Both projects will use my shared business rules dll, service dll, etc.

Comment: You can go with that approach, but I believe you can fix it in a single project

Comment: Matias I have updated my question, I have added a new route that seems to work but still having the duplication on Common Controller, how can I tell my razor that I want to call portal controllers.

Comment: The issue isn't that. The problem here is the MVC route matches a WebAPI one and viceversa

Comment: Exactly thats the issue... Ohh lord I hate when i can't figure out this way. Well Matias anyway I appreciate so much your help. I think I will go for Plan B: other separate application :(

Comment: Why don't you read my solution in the possible duplicate? It should solve the issue!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use areas for your case.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Billing_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

And you need update Application_Start method

```
protected void Application_Start() 
{ 
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

[Area in MVC 5 with example - step by step](http://www.itorian.com/2013/10/area-in-mvc-5-with-example-step-by-step.html)